# how can I generate a unique int from a unique string in dataframe

Tags: python, machine-learning, knn

I want to run the k- nearest neighbor method in the dataset which some of its columns related to Id are in string format. I should convert all the strings to numbers in order to use them in knn algorithm. How can I convert string Id in the dataset to unique int as Id?
(As these strings are Id it is important that we have the same int for the same string in each column. should I use hash instead of cast it to int?

I tried to use cast string to int but it had this error:

ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'VkSa32MyS738HMkfk4tEfk'

here is dataset:
http://gitlab.rahnemacollege.com/rahnemacollege/tuning-registration-JusticeInWork/raw/master/dataset.csv

here is a piece of code related to this:

```
for i in range(1, 24857):
  df.iloc[i,0]=int(df.iloc[i,0]) 
  df.iloc[i,1]=int(df.iloc[i,1]) 
  df.iloc[i,3]=int(df.iloc[i,3]) 
  df.iloc[i,8]=int(df.iloc[i,8]) 
  df.iloc[i,9]=int(df.iloc[i,9]) 
  df.iloc[i,10]=int(df.iloc[i,10]) 
  df.iloc[i,11]=int(df.iloc[i,11]) 
  df.iloc[i,12]=int(df.iloc[i,12])
```

here is my total code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from google.colab import files
!pip install sklearn
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsClassifier
from sklearn.metrics import classification_report, confusion_matrix
#-----------------read file-------------------
uploaded = files.upload()
with open('dataset.csv', 'r') as data:
   df3 = pd.read_csv(data , encoding = ('ansi'))
   lst = ['id', 'Prold', 'ProCreationId', 'CustCreatonRate', 'TaskCreationTimestamp', 'Price', 'ServiceId', 'CategoryId', 'ZoneId', 'TaskState', 'TargetProId', 'isFraud']
   df = pd.DataFrame(df3)
   print (df)

#----------------------preprocessing----------------

for i in range(1, 24857):
  df.iloc[i,0]=int(df.iloc[i,0]) 
  df.iloc[i,1]=int(df.iloc[i,1]) 
  df.iloc[i,3]=int(df.iloc[i,3]) 
  df.iloc[i,8]=int(df.iloc[i,8]) 
  df.iloc[i,9]=int(df.iloc[i,9]) 
  df.iloc[i,10]=int(df.iloc[i,10]) 
  df.iloc[i,11]=int(df.iloc[i,11]) 
  df.iloc[i,12]=int(df.iloc[i,12]) 

#----------------------set data-----------------------

  x = df.iloc[:,0:12]

  y = df.iloc[:,13]

  X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(x, y, test_size=0.3)
  print(X_train.shape, y_train.shape)
  print(X_test.shape, y_test.shape)
   #-------------------------normalize-----------------
  scaler = StandardScaler()
  scaler.fit(X_train)
  X_train = scaler.transform(X_train)
  X_test = scaler.transform(X_test)
   #-----------------------------knn----------------
  classifier = KNeighborsClassifier(n_neighbors=5)
  classifier.fit(X_train, y_train)
  y_pred = classifier.predict(X_test)
   #-------------------------result-----------------
  print(confusion_matrix(y_test, y_pred))
  print(classification_report(y_test, y_pred))
```

how can I fix it?

Thank for your consideration.

Comment: Okay, so if the string is for example `'VkSa32MyS738HMkfk4tEfk'`, then what integer result should be calculated? What is the rule that tells you so?

Comment: It would be a symbol for this string. for example: we can use 12 instead of VkSa32MyS738HMkfk4tEfk and if this string would be seen again in column we should consider it as 12.

Comment: So, any value, as long as it is a consistent, one-to-one mapping?

Comment: It is valuable as we need to use numerical data in knn method instead of strings.

Answer (score 0):

We can try the categorical data :

```
In [553]: x = pd.Series(['a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'c']).astype('category')

In [554]: x
Out[554]: 
0    a
1    a
2    a
3    b
4    b
5    c
dtype: category
Categories (3, object): [
                        a
                        , b
                        , c]

In [555]: x.cat.codes
Out[555]: 
0    0
1    0
2    0
3    1
4    1
5    2
dtype: int8
```

refer : https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.16.2/categorical.html